# jQuery changes classes but css does not change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am new at learning how to change classes with JQuery. In my example, the hexagons change classes in the DOM, but no CSS is applied. Am I missing something obvious?

Thank you for your time!

```js
$('#hexagon1').click(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("unclicked");
  $(this).addClass("clicked");
});

$('#hexagon2').click(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("unclicked");
  $(this).addClass("clicked");
});
```

```css
.clicked {
  fill: #0000FF;
}

.unclicked {
  fill: #0000FF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg viewBox="0 0 101.83981 74.999893" id="svg8">
  <g
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(-28.970265,-13.579265)">
    <path
       style="opacity:1;fill:#ffb619;stroke-width:4.50001;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:7"
       id="hexagon1"
       d="M 43.906288,64.275181 28.970265,39.449215 43.002172,14.101257 71.9701,13.579265 86.906123,38.405231 72.874217,63.753189 Z" class="unclicked"/>
    <path
       style="opacity:1;fill:#008000;stroke-width:4.50001;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:7"
       id="hexagon2"
       d="M 87.810242,88.579156 72.874219,63.753189 86.906125,38.405231 115.87405,37.883239 130.81008,62.709205 116.77817,88.057164 Z" class="unclicked"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: `clicked` and `unclicked` has the same color

Comment: The inline style applied to the `path` is more specific so will override whatever you put in your class (you can see that when inspecting the element). Either use `!important` within your css class or use a class for the base style as well. I would recommend the latter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you have used inline `style` attributes which override any external style rules.

To fix this you need to organise your CSS so that the rules of `.clicked` and `.unclicked` are specific enough to override any default styling. You also need to make the `fill` colour of both of those classes different, as in your example they are identical and will make no difference. Try this:

```js
$('.hexagon').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("unclicked clicked"); // note the single use of toggleClass here
});
```

```css
.hexagon {
  opacity: 1;
  stroke-width: 4.50001;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 7;
}

.hexagon1 { fill: #ffb619; }
.hexagon2 { fill: #008000; }
svg path.clicked { fill: #0000FF; }
svg path.unclicked { fill: #CC0000; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg viewBox="0 0 101.83981 74.999893" id="svg8">
  <g id="layer1" transform="translate(-28.970265,-13.579265)">
    <path class="hexagon hexagon1 unclicked" d="M 43.906288,64.275181 28.970265,39.449215 43.002172,14.101257 71.9701,13.579265 86.906123,38.405231 72.874217,63.753189 Z" />
    <path class="hexagon hexagon2 unclicked" d="M 87.810242,88.579156 72.874219,63.753189 86.906125,38.405231 115.87405,37.883239 130.81008,62.709205 116.77817,88.057164 Z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It worked perfectly. I was making an obvious mistake. haha

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `!important` to the style rules.

This is because you also set fill in the style attribute of the paths which overwrites the fill rule from your classes

Comment: Thank you for explaining it. I understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

1. you have inline-styles in both the cases, so all the properties in inline-style will not be applied as inline-styles have higher specifity.
2. Both `unclicked` and `clicked` have the same CSS

   ```
   .clicked {
     fill: #0000FF;
   }

   .unclicked {
    fill: #0000FF;
   }
   ```

To make it work either use `!important` in your JQuery or avoid inline-style initially and apply styles in a CSS file. Plus you definitely need to use different `fill` color in both the cases.